Is there a clean way to handle reuse of try...except blocks that force early function return?
I'm writing an Azure Functions API, with many different endpoints with similar internal behavior. One major step in each endpoint is to take each naked POST and parse out any and all arguments (comes in as a dictionary) to a custom request object I define that can be further used for all function behavior. Each request object expects certain keys to be present in the request's data, and I raise exceptions within the object to direct program flow within the main function towards an early response with error code.
My main question is: I have to reuse these try...except blocks in every function as I want the responses to be the same, is there a way to abstract this out to a single reusable block?
This is an example of how one endpoint would look:
from requests import ShowUsersRequest

def my_endpoint(req: azure.functions.HttpRequest):
    try:
        wrapped_request = ShowUsersRequest(req)
    except KeyError:
        return func.HttpResponse('Request missing argument(s)', status_code=400)
    except ValueError as e:
        return func.HttpResponse(f'One or more request arguments was of invalid type. {e.args[0]}', status_code=400)

    ... # rest of function continues

And what a request object would look like:
# requests.py

class ShowUsersRequest:
    def __init__(self, req: func.HttpRequest) -> None:
        # KeyErrors would arise from a missing key in the params dict
        self.identifier = req.params['account_identifier']
        self.client_code = int(req.params['client_code'])
 
        # raise ValueError to represent some kind of validation problem
        if self.client_code < 0:
            raise ValueError('Client code must be non-negative')


Maybe you can do it with a decorator. Other than that, I don't think Python has any way to simplify this. It's the kind of thing you might do with a macro, but Python doesn't have them.

The way I ended up doing this is with the following pattern by defining a decorator that would handle the needed errors. The reason this works is that I've declared narrow custom exceptions MissingArgumentError and ValidationError in order to not catch other possible exceptions like ValueError that may arise.
# requests.py

# ValidationError and MissingArgumentError are user defined

class ShowUsersRequest:
    def __init__(self, req: func.HttpRequest) -> None:
        # KeyErrors would arise from a missing key in the params dict
        try:
            self.identifier = req.params['account_identifier']
            self.client_code = int(req.params['client_code'])
        except KeyError as e:
            raise MissingArgumentError from e 

        # raise ValidationError to represent some kind of validation problem
        if self.client_code < 0:
            raise ValidationError('Client code must be non-negative')

# req_handler.py

from azure.functions import HttpResponse
from typing import Callable, Any
from utilities.errors import MissingArgumentError, ValidationError
from functools import wraps

def handle_request_errors(func: Callable[..., Any]):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args: list[Any], **kwargs: dict[Any, Any]):
        try:
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        except MissingArgumentError:
            return HttpResponse('Request missing argument(s)', status_code=400)
        except ValidationError as e:
            return HttpResponse(f'One or more request arguments failed validation. {e.args[0]}', status_code=400)
    
    return decorated

from requests import ShowUsersRequest
from req_handler import handle_request_errors

@handle_request_errors
def my_endpoint(req: azure.functions.HttpRequest):
    wrapped_request = ShowUsersRequest(req)

    ... # rest of function continues



that!
Maybe just add the description in English that this modification: custom exceptions for the repeating part, allow the decorator to be used without catching other exceptions that should otherwise be treated differently.
